# Como transcrever gaguejamento?

Tags: ortografia

Quando uma pessoa gagueja, seja por algum problema de dicção ou por puro nervosismo, algumas letras ou mesmo sílabas inteiras acabam se duplicando.

Mas e como transcrever isso corretamente?

Devo repetir escrito tantas letras/sílabas quantas a pessoa gaguejou no áudio/vídeo ou uma ou duas vezes já basta, apenas para caracterizar que ela está gaguejando?

Se a palavra gaguejada por um nome próprio e/ou estiver no começo de uma frase, a primeira letra repetida vem minúscula ou maiúscula. Ex:

> N-N-Não faça isso!

Ou então:

> N-n-não faça isso!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei até que ponto esta é uma questão gramatical.

A gagueira, nesse caso, é uma onomatopeia. Se você vir as [regras gramaticais](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&id=16-49&version=1943) vai perceber que as onomatopeias só caem no caso das iniciais maiúsculas quando estão no início de um período:

> No começo do período, verso ou citação direta: Disse o Padre Antônio
>   Vieira: "Estar com Cristo em qualquer lugar, ainda que seja no
>   Inferno, é estar no. Paraíso". "Auriverde pendão de minha terra, Que a
>   brisa do Brasil beija e balança, Estandarte que à luz do sol encerra
>   As promessas divinas da Esperança..." (Castro Alves.)

Com base nisso, afirmaria que a forma correta de escrever é:

> N-n-não faça isso!

Eu ainda mudaria o *N* para *nã*, já que não falamos N mas nã:

> Nã nã não faça isso!

O próprio travessão não tem muito sentido aqui já que não há palavras mas letras.

Comment: Faz todo sentido. Vou apenas aguardar mais possíveis opiniões, se alguma, antes de assinalar a melhor resposta

Comment: Depende do que ele gaguejou "Na não fa fa faça isso!"

Comment: tenho uma questão:
quando o "gaguejamento" não é silábico, mas antes o famoso "aaaa..." ou "aaaam...", como se pode fazer neste caso?
obrigada